# Button not like Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox

Hello , I have little problem with this html script :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <td>
    <form name="tsform">
      <p align="center">
        <font face="Arial">Choisir un Pseudo :
         <br>
         <input type="text" name="NICKNAME"><br />
         <input type="button"  value="Se connecter" onClick="javascript:location.href='ts3server://ts.xxxxxxxxx.fr/?port=9987&channel=Accueil&nickname=' + tsform.NICKNAME.value">
       </font>
      </p>
    </form>
    </a>
  </td>
</body>

</html>
```

This scipt work fine if you click , but I want click and push Enter key

I modify :

```
input type="button"  value="Se connecter"
```

to

```
input type="submit"  value="Se connecter"
```

And work fine only on FireFox , not work on IE and Chrome

Have you any idea ?

Comment: English is probably not your first language but you should try putting a little more work into the grammar of your question, that being said your html only listens for the `onClick` event. You need to tell it to listen for both clicks and keydowns

Answer (score 1):

One I would suggest using a submit button just a lot less annoying than onClick, and have modified the form made it cleaner and easy to see (also i left your `<br />` tags in but i would suggest you dont use them and use css instead)

```
<td>
    <form name="tsform"action="ts3server://ts.xxxxxxxxx.fr/"method="get">
        <input type="hidden" name="port" value="9987"><input type="hidden" name="channel" value="Accueil">
        <p align="center">
            <font face="Arial">Choisir un Pseudo :
                <br>
                <input type="text" name="NICKNAME">
                <br />
                <input type="submit" value="Se connecter" />
            </font>
        </p>
    </form>
    </a>
</td>
```

Comment: Hi , I use your code and it's work very well thanks you very much

Answer (score 0):

Add the action attribute to the form tag:

```
<form name="tsform" action="javascript:location.href='ts3server://ts.xxxxxxxxx.fr/?port=9987&channel=Accueil&nickname=' + tsform.NICKNAME.value">
```

Answer (score 0):

Pressing enter will submit the form but since there is no action (eg. URL) the submission doesn't do anything. I would utilize the default form behaviour and add the URL to an action attribute on the form element as well as setting the method (eg. get). Then add the 2 default values (port and channel) to hidden inputs.

Also, rather than attaching an onClick event listener to the button I would use a submit button which will trigger the same form submit as pressing enter.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
      <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <td>
        <form name="tsform" action="ts3server://ts.xxxxxxxxx.fr/" method="get">
            <input type="hidden" name="port" value="9987">
            <input type="hidden" name="channel" value="Accueil">
            <p align="center">
                <font face="Arial">Choisir un Pseudo :
                    <br>
                    <input type="text" name="nickname">
                    <br />
                    <input type="submit" value="Se connecter" />
                </font>
            </p>
        </form>
        </a>
    </td>
</body>

</html>
```